# how to substract two dates in django?

Tags: python, django, datetime

i am trying to subtracts 'end time' of a ride from its 'start time'. starttime is fetched directly from database(models.py) and line 'start = n[0].driverStarttime' indicates that. Now i use current datetime as 'endtime' of a ride. Variable 'diff' is used to subtract end and start time. but it gives
'TypeError at /driver_panel/endtrip
can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes' error. here driver_panel is my application in project. Driverbooking table is used to fetch start time. DateTimeField is used for store start and endtime. here is the code...

```
def endtrip(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        dbid = request.GET.get('driverBookID')
        if dbid:
            n = Driverbooking.objects.all().filter(driverBookID=dbid)
            name = n[0].customerID
            start = n[0].driverStartTime
            end = datetime.datetime.now()

            diff = end - start

            total = diff * 10
            a = Driverbooking.objects.get(driverBookID=dbid)
            a.driverStatus = "end"
            a.driverEndTime = end
            a.driverAmount = total
            a.save()

            did = request.session['uid']
            x = Driverside.objects.all().filter(driverID=did)
            rate = x[0].driverFPH
            d = Driverside.objects.get(driverID=did)
            d.driverIsAvailable = "yes"
            d.save()
            context = {"name":name,"start":start,"end":end,"rate":rate,"t":total}
            return render(request, "driverbill.html", context)
            return redirect('driverhome')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem raises because you seem to be subtracting "start time" (which probably has timezone info) and "end time" (which has no timezone).

Simple solution is to use the correct current time with timezone, like [the `timezone` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects) suggest.

Instead of this line:

```
end = datetime.datetime.now()
```

try this:

```
from django.utils import timezone as tz
end = tz.now()
```